# Problems with Opera's launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, opera

When I install Opera and open it the first time an Opera launcher shows up in Unity. I then set it to be kept. However, after having used Opera a couple of times the launcher stops working, and when I open Opera from the Applications menu I either get no Opera launcher, or I get another icon for Opera Widget managemnt. It's like Unity "forgets" Opera and thinks the widget manager/installer is he Opera application. Since Opera works fine in Gnome this seems to be a Unity problem. Any idea how to resolve it? I'm using Opera 11.10 Beta on fully updated Natty Beta x64.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 11.04 is currently in Beta so things might not work right. Please [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on this issue.

Comment: Bug has already been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/754019

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the latest ubuntu 11.04 + updates and the latest opera release.
Unstick opera from unity launcher, remove/purge opera, download it and install it again.