# Opera widget installer starts every time

Tags: software-installation, opera, widgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with Opera's launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33971/problems-with-operas-launcher)

I am wondering why does an Opera Widget Installer show up every-time I run opera?.

I already purged it and re-installed to no avail. I tried looking everywhere within Opera to see if I could disable it and found none. Trying to activate the Icon also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of [Problems with Opera's launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33971/problems-with-operas-launcher)

However, that questions (and the launchpad link) mention Ubuntu 11.04 beta, and Opera 11.01, while I'm using a clean install of both Ubuntu 11.04 final and Opera 11.10 final.